# What is the average waiting time for a paper deposited to an open archive such as HAL?

Tags: publications, preprint, repository

I recently deposited a research article to the [HAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Articles_en_Ligne) open archive, and I am waiting for a PDF version of this article to be reviewed and made available online through this archive.

It seems as if papers which were deposited after my paper was deposited are now being uploaded, so I’m concerned that I might have somehow uploaded my article incorrectly.

So it is natural to ask: What is the average waiting time for a paper deposited to an open archive such as HAL? Also, when should I start to make inquiries to HAL concerning when my paper will be available online?

Comment: Usually, it seems that the waiting time for a paper between the deposit and the availability is one or two days. I remember a period one year ago in which I waited more than one month, but there was an uploading of the site. I do not know whether the statistics are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by Davide Giraudo, the waiting time is typically one or two open days. I think submissions are manually checked by a team in France, so if you submit on Saturday Australian time, you'll have to wait at least until Tuesday. If the team is very  busy, it can take a few more days.

Not asked but maybe worth mentioning: to check whether you are allowed to upload your article to an open archive such as HAL, type your journal name on [RoMEO](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/index.php) to get something like:

[image]