# Can I submit a paper to arXiv when it is still pending on Hal, and waiting to be transferred from HAL to arXiv?

Tags: phd, mathematics, arxiv, preprint, open-science

I submitted my first paper to [HAL](https://hal.halpreprod.archives-ouvertes.fr/) over eight days ago. It is still on awaiting moderation status.
When I deposed it on Hal, I checked the box indicating that I wanted it transferred to arXiv. But since my paper is pending on Hal, can I submit it to arXiv myself? Or will there be, at the end of the day, two versions of the same paper on arXiv, the one I submit and the one transferred by HAL?

P.S. I am a mathematics Ph.D. student, and this is my first paper.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. Otherwise your question will be closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the average waiting time for a paper deposited to an open archive such as HAL?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72864/what-is-the-average-waiting-time-for-a-paper-deposited-to-an-open-archive-such-a)

Comment: I disagree that this a duplicate, the other question asks about waiting times with HAL, this asks if one can submit to arXiv meanwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend waiting longer for HAL's moderation process to run its course, not least to avoid wasting arXiv volunteer moderators' time. Be sure the HAL submission isn't stuck because the moderation team sent a request you didn't notice or respond to.

On arXiv's end, the moderation process and automatic scans for textual overlaps will very likely detect such duplicate submissions and stop double posting from happening. Here is the relevant bullet point from the documentation page for [Third party submission](https://info.arxiv.org/help/third_party_submission.html):

> - As part of moderation, arXiv does not accept duplicate content. If a work already exists on arXiv then any new versions should be replacements of the existing arXiv version. In cases where an author already has a paper on arXiv and the same paper or updated version of the same paper is submitted from a proxy, the submission will not be accepted as a new work. arXiv will inform the proxy of the existing arXiv identifier and how to post the new version as a replacement.